# Need an r function to invert the longitude coordinates for a geom_sf ggplot chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found Kim Fitters excellent solution for Celestial Mapping (https://kimnewzealand.github.io/2019/02/21/celestial-maps/) 
and used it quite successfully to make a plot of meteor radiants. But then trying to be clever, I added the geoJSON constellations on top of my plot and noticed that they are all inverted. ie they are drawn on the surface of the earth … which is opposite in east/west orientation. So Orion's bow is to his left whereas it is to his right if you look up into the sky.[attached image shows Geminids plot with constellations overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTqRc.jpg) 
 Is there a simple way to convert/flip all my longitudes so that the results look as they do in the sky ?

Regards,
Steve Bosley.

PS I originally posted this question as a supplemental on a different post ([R: plotting sky map in Mollweide projection in galactic coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130539/r-plotting-sky-map-in-mollweide-projection-in-galactic-coordinate-system)) but was advised to raise it as a separate question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add some data and code of your attempts?

Comment: Are all constellations inverted across the prime meridian?  Eastern hemisphere constellations appear in the western hemisphere?

Comment: essentially yes, but with north still north and south still south. Imagine wrapping the plot around the earth … that is what the Mollweide CRS transformation is giving me (see the attached image) … what I actually want is the sky view which is the same as looking at that plot you just wrapped around the earth from underneath ie the centre of the earth … assuming a degree of transparency :-)

Comment: s_t … the code and data are in the Link to Kim Fitters solution … but her code gets the same result most eloquently, and I am looking for a way to rectify it so I can use it for my own project … Steve

Comment: Can you use st_coordinates() on your constellation data and multiply all longitude by -1 to 'flip' it longitudinally?  I'm assuming that lon is [-180, 180]

Comment: Thanks, mrhellmann … st_coordinates() certainly allows me to unpack the geometry so that I can flip it, but I'm struggling to get it back into an _sf object to present to ggplot …. and yes lon is [-180, 180] … ultimately I may need to convert that to is [360, 0] but I think I can see how to achieve that (famous last words!)